# In dynamic listbox how to get multiple selection item?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    var list = GetFilterItems().Select(g => g.GroupID).Distinct();
    ListBox lst;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        lst  = new ListBox();
        lst.Size = new Size(161, 82);
        lst.Name = item.ToString();
        lst.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

        lst.Location = new Point(x,y+25);

        pnlFilters.Controls.Add(lst);
        lst.Click += new EventHandler(lst_Click);
        x += lst.Width+5;
    }             
}

void lst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    ItemChanged(sender);
}

private void ItemChanged(object sender)
{
    // Get the selected ListBox
    ListBox selectedListViewControl = (ListBox)sender;

    // Get the ListBox's items
    List<FilterItem> currentFilterItems = selectedListViewControl.Items.Cast<FilterItem>().ToList();

    // Get the ListBox's selected items
    List<FilterItem> selectedFilterItems = selectedListViewControl.SelectedItems.Cast<FilterItem>().ToList();
}
```

In above code i got only 1 selected item even i select multiple item from listbox
how to get multiple item form listbox

Comment: `Please give me soultion` is not right way to ask. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: You are creating a new list box for each item in your list. And handling the click event. Why are you expecting it to have multiple items in there?

Comment: @ryadavilli i need that click event according to that selected list box item the parent and child listbox items are populated

Comment: @ryadavilli ok i got the solution of that use the mouseup event 

lst.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(lst_MouseUp);

Answer (score 0):

just create one listbox, then add all items to this single one

then the multi selection works